# Unable to Restrict YouTube Data API key to Android App

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

As the title says I'm having trouble restricting use of the YouTube Data API key by Android App.

**What I've done so far:**

- Went on **Google Cloud Platform - Restrict API Key** page
- Under Application Restrictions selected **Android**.
- Added the item: entered app's package and SHA-1 fingerprint (obtained from Playstore console)
- Under API restrictions checked **"Restrict Key"**.
- In the following drop-down selected **YouTube Data API V3**.
- Clicked **"Save"**.

**Obtaining SHA-1 Fingerprint:**

- On **Google Play Console** Selected the application.
- Expanded **Setup** to open **App Integrity**.
- Copied SHA-1 fingerprint from under **App signing key certificate**.

I now believe I've completed all the steps as outlined in the [Applying API Key Restrictions - Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en-GB&visit_id=637508306262387129-4158655110&rd=1#api_key_restrictions) page. However YouTube Data API calls are still failing with 403. Am I missing something?

Here is my request from debug app: I realize that should fail expectedly but I can't turn on network logging for the current app without pushing an app update.

```
GET: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=Mkq8pnvsnQg&key=API_KEY
```

One thing I've noticed is that there are no Android app identifying markers present i.e. no way to tell if it the request was made from Android or any other platform, so maybe I'm missing something there?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the API with restricted access from a debug app. When it is uploaded to the device - it is signed with a development key which SHA1 is different from the one you use on playstore.

You should add one more SHA1 key to the restriction list - your development key. [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) is how to do it. Only after that, you will be able to use it on the debug app.

You can also app `debuggable = true` and `minifiedEnabled = false` to the release build variant settings in Gradle in order to be able to debug of release app - just don't forget to change it back before submitting to play store.

If you are still not able to use the app even on release build signed with the correct certificate - it means that either you have entered the wrong SHA1 and the wrong package name or did not provided all the needed [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) to the Google Sign-in.

Comment: I've clearly stated I'm copying the SHA-1 signature from the Google Play Console and not the signature of the keystore file I've generated myself. Yes, I'd also tried adding the debug SHA-1 fingerprint and running the debug app (Which also failed the success call).

Comment: I've already repeatedly checked and verified the SHA-1 fingerprint and the package name and they are correct. Can you tell me why I'd need to provide Google Sign-In scopes?

Comment: I'm simply using the API to play public videos and retrieve the video's information.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue, were you able to resolve it @Abbas

Comment: @Apoorvpandey nope.